# How can I implement a function take as some optional parameters in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a function that takes 3 determined parameters and one additional parameter.

In Matlab, I can use **nargin < 4** to distinguish the case with the addtional parameter and that without the addtional parameter.

How can I implement a function in C++ imitating this behavior?

I found parameter pack / variadic parameter may be helpful, but I have no idea how to use it.

Can someone shed some info to me?

Comment: Does the 1 additional parameter have a value that it can default to if not set by the person using the code? You may just want to use a default last parameter or if that is not an option use std::optional

Comment: @drescherjm If I use a default last parameter paradigm, how can the function itself know whether the user passes 3 parameters or 4 parameters?

Comment: The function will not know unless you can use the value to indicate this. Perhaps `-1`  or even `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()` will never be valid for the user to enter and you can check for this value. This is why I asked if this is an option. If not the simplest method is the current answer. I think @Vasilij did a good job with the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional). In the function declaration, assign the default value of `std::nullopt` to your optional argument. This is a special value designed to indicate that `std::optional` doesn't contain any value. Thus, you'll be able to call your function with 3 or 4 parameters.

```
void function(int a, int b, int c, std::optional<int> d = std::nullopt) {
   // check if d has value (there is a special bool conversion in std::optional)
   if (d) {
      int temp = d.value();
   }
}

int main() {
    function(0,1,2);
    function(0,1,2,3);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use parameter pack as following for similar behaviour:

```
#include <iostream>

//template function, takes any number of argument
template <typename... Args>
int func(Args... args)
{
    //sizeof...(args) is the number of args provided
    switch (sizeof...(args)) {
        case 4:
            std::cout << "4"; break;
        case 2:
            std::cout << "2"; break;
        default:
            std::cout << "Args: " << sizeof...(args);
    }
}

int main()
{
    func(1,2,3); //prints "Args: 3"
}
```

Comment: It gets trickier when you care about what those arguments' values actually are.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I implement a function in C++ imitating this behavior?

That depends on what exactly you're going to do inside that function in case of 3 actual arguments and 4 actual arguments. If those actions are very similar -- then you'd better go with the `std::optional<>` approach, as suggested before.

However if those actions are substantially different, then you may want to simply **overload** that function. I.e. have *two* functions with the same name: one for 3 arguments and another one for 4 arguments, with absolutely independent bodies. The compiler will be able to figure which implementation to call.

```
#include <iostream>

void MyFunc(int a, int b, int c)
{
    std::cout << "3-argument version called." << std::endl;
}

void MyFunc(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    std::cout << "4-argument version called." << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    MyFunc(1, 2, 3);
    MyFunc(1, 2, 3, 4);
}
```